# Algorithm contests - Unknown number of test cases

Tags: c, input

There are some problems in algorithms contests (or problems on e.g. SPOJ) with unknown number of test cases in input. How can I read them in proper way without TLE?

Thanks in advance.

`SPOJ` - sphere Online Judge

`TLE` - Time Limit Exceeded

Comment: Read until you 'find' EOF indicator?

Comment: well after answering SPOJ on wikipedia i remain stuck on TLE, what that acronym stands for ?

Comment: what is SPOJ and TLE :-) JA (just asking)

Comment: SPOJ - http://www.spoj.com/ | TLE - Time Limit Exceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it:

```
while(scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Note that it will also break the loop if any reading error occures (which is probably what you want anyway..)